# rearranging the elements in list

Tags: c#, linq, list

Hi just needed suggestion regarding List /LINQ etc

```
public  static List<Employee> Employees()
       {
          return Adapters.WebServiceAdapter.getInstance.SELECT_EMPLOYEES().ToList();
       }
```

This is returning USERID , USERNAME in ASC order of USERID as below

```
   USERID USERNAME
        1      FirstUser
        2      SecondUser
        3      ThirdUser
        4      FourthUser
        5      FifthUser
```

I have requirement of rearranging the output based on the currently logged Employee.

For Example i have information that USERID 4TH IS LOGGED in my website then this function 
should return me

```
 USERID USERNAME
    4     FourthUser
    1     FirstUser
    2     SECONDUSER
    3     THIRDUSER
    5     FIFTHUSER
```

Just to give reason why i am doing this - I have a drop-downs various places in my website and i want to ensure that if this function is called to load my dropdown lists . By default the currently logged user should be selected by default.

I appreciate if someone could provide valuable inputs..

Comment: What have you tried?  Questions are generally expected to not just ask  "how do you do this" but to help you with specific issues that you are having getting your own code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just combine two lists using Union](https://compilify.net/2w0)

Link's Code:

```
    var numbers = new List<Int32>{1,2,3,4,5};
    var loggedInUsers = numbers.Where(x=>x == 4);
    var restOfUsers = numbers.Where(x=>x != 4);
    var joinedLists = loggedInUsers.Union(restOfUsers).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! i was busy checking other options as well but this saved me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this trick:
Insert your logged user in position 0 of the list, then call distinct.

```
MyList.Insert(0,MyList.Single(c => c.UserID == IDofLoggedUser));
var lst = MyList.Distinct();
```

Result:

```
the original list ordered by ID like you have
MyList = 1,2,3,4,5,6;
then insert for example logged user has ID of 4
MyList = 4,1,2,3,4,5,6;
then call distinct,it will find and maintain the first 4,and remove second 4, so final result:
MyList = 4,1,2,3,5,6;
```